# getting wrong center of frame for detail view for UISplitView

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

learning SWIFT. I can't seem to access bounds from my view... no matter what platform I work in the bounds return the same values (600,600).

I have a graphView : UIView & controller embedded in a navigationController as the Detail of a SplitViewController.

I am trying to get the center of my graphView : UIView on screen (the **Detail** of the splitViewController), but center keeps returning a point too far to the right (in portrait)/bottom (in landscape).

I tried accessing it multiple ways, but maybe my understanding of it is wrong?

example: `var screenCenter: CGPoint = convertPoint( center, fromView: superview)`

```
    println("bounds are  \(bounds)") // view boundaries
    println("frame is at \(frame)")  // frame where the view resides
    println(" center is at       \(center)")
    println(" ScreenCenter is at \(screenCenter)")
```

(output)

```
bounds are  (0.0,0.0,600.0,600.0)
frame is at (0.0,0.0,600.0,600.0)
 center is at       (300.0,300.0)
 ScreenCenter is at (300.0,300.0)
```

-> how do I actually get to the center? Is SplitView geography joint master + detail?

<strike>-> it seem the x positioning is correct in portrait (but not the y), and the y is correct in portrait (but not the x)</strike>

Comment: Try CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.yourCustomView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.yourCustomView.bounds));

Comment: in what method do you try to get this value ?

Comment: I have center / screenCenter assigned in my GraphView : UIView class.
I try drawing / get ouput from overriding drawRect

Comment: I am trying Avijit's suggestion to no avail, but self can't seem to link to GraphView directly... tried self.(GraphView) but can't seem to get to bounds.

Comment: _when_ are you reading those value out? the final on-screen frame is defined when the view pushed into the view-hierarchy, therefore you will not get the final frame _before_ that. try to read the value of the frame in `–viewWillAppear:` method, maybe, instead of the `–viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: I added a property observer in my GraphViewController that triggers on the Outlet (GraphView) being set & forces a graphView.setNeedsDisplay() - which callsdrawRect() from GraphView, pulling the values listed, so not through viewDidLoad()... but after checking the view hierarchy tool it seem that the GraphView itself is the one with the wrong values (others are constrained within expected bounds while the GraphView is suddenly bigger than them all.... looking into it.

Comment: I got it - the final view was missing default constraints and it was using the default 600,600 values. "Reset to Suggested Constraints" fixed the issue - I learned some about exploring the view hierarchy for a simple autolayout issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! the graphView in Storyboard was missing constraints and using the default 600,600 values. "Reset to Suggested Constraints" in storyboard with the view selected fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use storyboard this can help.
Create a `view` where you set up the `autoconstraints` to false.
`Constraint` the `view` to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.It will find the centre of your secondary view or detail view.

```
  var logoView :UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.backgroundColor = .green
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(logoView)
    logoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    logoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    logoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    }
```